# PHP code is not working in html tags

Tags: php, html, url, echo

So, I am creating my own error page. And it takes some information from the url.

Here is a code in the top of the error.php

```
<?php
$error_message = $_GET["error_message"];

if(!$error_message) {
    $error_message = "вы оказались здесь из-за сбоя в работе программы.";
}

echo $error_message;
?>
```

And it works fine. But when I am trying to echo this vatiable in my html code below, nothing happens:

```
<p>Нам очень жаль, но произошел сбой. Вероятно, <span class="error"><?php echo $error_messsage ?></span>.</p>
```

I really cant understand, where my problem is.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: check ur variable name its $error_message not $error_messsage

Comment: turn on the error reporting and see what the error is. and `$error_message = isset($_GET["error_message"]) ? $_GET["error_message"] : false;`

Comment: Oh. Yeah, it was obvious. How can I missed it? Thank you) The porblem was in $error_messsage - sss

Comment: also, you should check if `$error_message` is set ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a spelling error in your HTML code. It should be:

```
<p>Нам очень жаль, но произошел сбой. Вероятно, <span class="error"><?php echo $error_message ?></span>.</p>
```

One too many "s"s in the variable name in your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Typo error sir :)

```
<p>Нам очень жаль, но произошел сбой. Вероятно, <span class="error"><?php echo $error_message ?></span>.</p>
```

Too many s on $error_message;

Comment: Please edit your answer to describe what your fix was (that there were too many 's' in $error_message)